# Javascript property as var

Tags: javascript, properties, global-variables

If I declare a property(itemSize, in my case) in the global scope without the word var, the code works

```
var vbo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(vertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
vbo.itemSize = 3;//This line works
```

If I declare the same property in with the word var, the code doesn't work and the console says Unexpected token .

```
var vbo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(vertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
var vbo.itemSize = 3; //Unexpected token "."
```

Whereas if I declare vbo.itemsize inside a function it works again. Why can't I set a property as var in the global scope? Shouldn't the property be read as window.vbo.itemsize?

Comment: `vbo.itemSize = 3` is not declaring a variable in global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can, the problem is you're declaring `vbo` **and** assigning a value to its `itemSize` property, which causes the interpreter to try to declare a variable called `vbo.itemSize`. Since you can't declare variables with a period in their name, you get the specified error. this code:

```
vbo.itemSize = 3;//This line works
```

doesn't create a new global variable, it creates an `itemSize` property on the `vbo` variable and assigns the value `3` to it, which is perfectly legal and has nothing to do with the scope of the `vbo` variable. the var in

```
var vbo.itemSize = 3; //Unexpected token "."
```

is also superfluous because the `vbo` variable is already declared. you can also assign the value to `vbo.itemSize` and a global `itemSize` by doing the following:

```
var itemSize = vbo.itemSize = 3
```

if you want to do this somwhere other than the global scope, do

```
window['itemSize'] = vbo.itemSize = 3
```

that will properly assign `3` to `vbo.itemSize` and a global `itemSize` (window is the global scope)

Comment: Very well said. Learned a thing or two.